# How can I modify a Windows 7 32 bit ISO to install in UEFI mode?

Tags: windows-7, boot, uefi, 32-bit

Long story short, I have a Windows 10 tablet that's running 32-bit Windows 10. I'd like to install 32-bit Windows 7, but the tablet's BIOS is UEFI only and doesn't have legacy/CSM boot options.

Is there any way I can modify a 32-bit Windows 7 ISO to boot on 32-bit UEFI only systems like one can do with Linux ISOs and `bootia32.efi`?

If not, how can I boot a 64-bit Windows 7 on my tablet's 32-bit UEFI?

Tablet specs:

> Insignia NS-P08W7100C
>
> - Intel ATOM CPU
> - 2GB RAM
> - 32GM EMMC

Comment: ["**Can Windows 7, Windows Vista, and Windows Server 2008 read, write, and boot from GPT disks?** Yes, all versions can use GPT partitioned disks for data. Booting is only supported for 64-bit editions on UEFI-based systems."](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/design/dn640535(v=vs.85))

Comment: if you really need to use Windows 7 you can run it in a virtual machine

Comment: I only have 2 gigs of ram and a VM would be too slow in this tablet. That's why I want to get 32 bit 7 running natively... even if it means trying to Frankenstein a bootable windows iso.

Comment: You could possibly-maybe get this working with a different bootloader (maybe GRUB?) to chainload into Windows. Maybe.

Comment: I was starting to think the same, cant find any tutorials online and dont know enough about grub to do it without.

Comment: Shim bootloader?

Answer (score 10):

> If not, how can I boot a 64 bit win 7 on my tablets 32 bit UEFI?

No;  Your device came with Windows 8+ because only Windows 8+ supports a 32-Bit UEFI kernel.  While your [processor](https://ark.intel.com/products/87383/Intel-Atom-x5-Z8300-Processor-2M-Cache-up-to-1_84-GHz) supports the 64-bit extension, Windows 7 32-bit cannot run on your device.

Only Windows 8+ supports booting a 64-bit operating system from a 32-bit UEFI kernel.  What you want is not possible.  *I suggest using Windows 10 instead.*

> Is there any way I can modify a 32-bit win 7 iso to boot on 32-bit UEFI only systems like one can with Linux isos and a bootia32.efi?

No.

> Q: Can Windows 7, Windows Vista, and Windows Server 2008 read, write, and boot from GPT disks?
>
> A: Booting is only supported for 64-bit editions on UEFI-based systems.

Source: [Answers about Windows disk support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/design/dn640535(v=vs.85)#answers-about-windows-disk-support)

> Anyway I can remove the 64-bit system files on my iso/USB and replace them with the ones from the 32 bit while preserving the 64-bit EFI booting?

No

Comment: @phuclv I quoted Microsoft, not Wikipedia, so citation of Wikipedia isn’t necessary.  **Your comment is confusing.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be [theoretically](https://github.com/maharmstone/quibble/issues/2#issuecomment-625555596) possible to use Windows on UEFI with mismatched bitness, but for the time being even the [nuttiest](https://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=20327&start=150) [hacks](https://superuser.com/questions/1055305/installing-windows-x64-on-32-bit-uefi-efi-ia32-via-grub) haven't been confirmed to be able to cross this boundary.

Anyway, this was just to dot the i's. Outside of the navel gazing, you can **directly** make Windows 7 32-bit UEFI-compatible. You just need the [x86 version](https://www.win-raid.com/t4035f45-Windows-XP-Bit-and-Server-Bit-on-Modern-Hardware-466.html#msg139107) of uefiseven and then [tinker](https://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=42051) a bit with W8's bootloader.

If people could pull this off with XP, it's surely possible.