# Should I keep 32bit or 64 bit Windows 10 on my x64 based Intel Atom Z3735F cpu on 2gb ram non-upgradable laptop

Tags: windows-10, 32-vs-64-bit

I have an Acer Aspire Switch 10 SW5-012 detachable notebook which has 2GB of RAM based on an x64 based processor. I got it with a 32 bit version of windows 8 but upgraded to windows 10 recently. But before I do anything else, I was considering if I'd be having Better performance with the 64 bit version of windows 10. Would it make my notebook perform better since it's based on an x64 based Intel Atom Z3735F? Or should I just stick to the 32 bit version of windows 10?

Comment: My inclination would be to upgrade to 64-bit Windows 10 (or a 64-bit Linux OS). It would *not* improve performance now, but it *would* enable you to make use of added RAM, At this time, another 2 GB is less than US$10.

Comment: I would stick with 32bit since you only have 2gb ram and cannot be upgraded.

Comment: This entirely depends on the processor.  There are a few Atom processors that while are indeed x64 were on machine with 32-bit UEFI kernels.  You cannot boot a 64-bit Windows operating system if you have a 32-bit UEFI kernel.  Since you have not provided that exact processor you have, it's difficult to determine, if that is the case.  **As this wasn't a problem for more recent Atom machines**

Comment: @NahianRifaat - You should be editing your question instead of submitting a comment that includes that type of vital information.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it make my notebook perform better since it's based on an x64 based Intel Atom?

I can almost guarantee you will see a noticeable drop in performance if you were to run a 64-bit operating system on your device.  Your device does indeed have a 32-bit bootloader.  This means you will be unable to run a 64-bit version of Windows 10 on your device.

What I can do is make the observation, that your system specifications, barely meet the minimum requirements for a 64-bit version of Windows 10.  **It's very unlikely you will see any performance gain from installing a 64-bit operating system on that device.**

> should I just stick to the 32 bit version of windows 10?

You are the only one that make this decision.  I am able to confirm that device does indeed have a 32-bit UEFI bootloader.  This means you will be unable to boot into a 64-bit version of Windows.  Linux does not have this same limitation.

Source:

[Possible to install 64-bit Windows on 32-bit UEFI?](https://superuser.com/questions/853009/possible-to-install-64-bit-windows-on-32-bit-uefi)

Comment: Please don't use the word "kernel" to describe UEFI firmware. It creates confusion with the OS kernel.